# Mapbox:How to access to react's component props on map's loaded event

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, layer

I'm trying to add some layers to a mapbox map.

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: this.mapContainer,
            style: "#my_url_style#",
            center: [this.state.lng, this.state.lat],
            zoom: this.state.zoom
        });

        this.map.on("load", function(){
            this.map.addLayer(this.props.dataLayers[0]);
        });
    }
```

However, as you can see, my layers are given to the component by a `prop`. As load function is executed on different context, I cannot access to `this.props...`

Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the function to arrow function. Code look likes

```
 this.map.on("load", function(){
            this.map.addLayer(this.props.dataLayers[0]);
        });
```

To

```
this.map.on("load", ()=>{
        console.log("load is working perfectly.");
            this.map.addLayer(this.props.dataLayers[0]);
        });
```